# Accessing data in Python from Firestore database without admin privelege

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to acces Firestore database. I'm working on a projet and need to analys its data but I only have reading rights on it. Therefore I can't generate an SDK key.

I tried with the pyrebase lib but it won't work:

```
import pyrebase
firebaseConfig = {
"I put here the config with apiKIey, authDomain etc..."}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)

#Get a reference to the database service
db = firebase.database()

#data to save
data = db.child("annonces").get()
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by reading rights? Aren’t enough to access data or what are you able with them? Are you sure you have enough privileges? And finally, do you have any problem using the Firestore’s official Python library? [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize) explains how to use it.

Comment: My role on the projet is "Reader" When I log in on the web console. Therefore i can't create a sdk admin key. However on the website, i can read the data

Comment: Have you considered using [Google Cloud client libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/client/libraries#google_cloud_client_libraries)? [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/client/libraries#references_and_resources_3) you’ll find Python resources.

Comment: I have the same need; I did not try yet but it looks promising: https://morioh.com/p/71358deec9e1

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the wrong python package. You can import firebase and firestore, as well as retrieve a collection as follows:

```py
    from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore, initialize_app

    firebaseConfig = {...}
    cred = credentials.Certificate(firebaseConfig)
    firebase_app = initialize_app(cred)
    db = firestore.client()

    data = []
    announce_docs = db.collection("users").stream()

    for doc in announce_docs:
        announcement = doc.to_dict()
        data.append(user)
```

You can find more info in the [Offical Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#python)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, I still hav ean error message : "DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application."

Comment: @OthmanBargach I just updated the answer. This method works for me, although I am using an environment variable for the firebase config. This solution should work for you if you decide to keep the config as a dict.

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! Although it still doesn't work, I get this error message : "Invalid service account certificate. Certificate must contain a "type" field set to "service_account"." My firebaseConfig is as a dict with {"apiKey" : "...", etc...}

Comment: In the doc about credentials.Certificate function, it seems the certificate I have to put in is a service account certificate, which i don't have access to ;(